# Resizing a UIButton after setting a new image

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, setneedsdisplay

I have a `UIButton` subclass that I animate whenever the user presses it. When it hasn't been pressed, the `UIButton` uses a "non-selected" image and looks great, but when the user presses it I set a new "selected" image.

This works great except the selected image is bigger than the non-selected image, so when the button sets the selected image, it does not resize to fit the new image.

The button is too small and the image is pinched in and looks distorted.

I tried calling some methods like `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` (separately, not together) after setting the new image but the button stays the same size.

How can I get the button to resize whenever I set a new image on it?

Comment: Did you set the content mode of the image to aspect fit? It might be the default, but I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Resizing the button has nothing to do with the contentMode property.

Comment: "The button is too small and the image is pinched and looks distorted" usually has everything to do with content mode. Also, you should just let the intrinsic content size drive the size of the button for the most part. Anyways, the button just inherits from UIView at the end of the day, which means you can just manipulate the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `button.frame` to the size of the image.